# If $w=f(z)=u+iv$, is analytic in a region R, then does $\frac{dw}{dz}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=-i\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}$ hold?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $w=f(z)=u+iv$, is analytic in a region R, then does $\frac{dw}{dz}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=-i\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}$ hold ?

$w=f(z)=u+iv$

Cauchy Riemann equations hold for w, therefore we have the following set of Cauchy Riemann equations,

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ --- (I)

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ --- (II)

Comment: What is dw/dz? The wirtinger derivative?

Comment: Yes! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Alex: $ \frac{dw}{dz}(a)=lim_{h\to 0} \frac{w(a+h)-w(a)}{h}$

Answer (score 1):

More generally (without assuming analyticity, only assuming the existence of 1st order partials): combine 
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial z} =\frac12\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}-i\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right) $$
and 
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z} =\frac12\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}+i\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\right) $$
to get 
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z} \tag1 $$
and 
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial y} = i\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}-i\frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z} \tag2$$
The Cauchy-Riemann equation says that $\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial \bar z}=0$, which allows (1) and (2) to simplify.